# django: How to customize display of ModelAdmin form based on user?

Tags: django

I have a Model that's managed by Django Admin. How to I customize the display of its edit form based on the currently logged in user? For example if someone other than the superuser is modifying the model, I want to hide certain fields.

It'd be great if I could set `fields` based on `request.user`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hackish way to do this is overwriting the `list_display` variable EVERY time the changelist view is called:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)
    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        user = request.user
        if user.is_superuser:
            self.list_display = ['field1', 'field2']
        else:
            self.list_display = ['field1']
        return super(MyModelAdmin, self).changelist_view(request, extra_context=None)
```

But set the variable every time to the desired value, since the same admin instance might be called for requests made by other users as well!

Comment: sorry made a mistake in my question, I really meant `fields` instead of `list_display`, but your suggestion should still apply

Answer (score 1):

An interesting approach to change edit form is to only alter readonly fields list.

For this purpose only override function **get_readonly_fields**:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        user = request.user
        if user.is_superuser:
            readonly = []
        else:
            readonly = ['field1']
        return readonly
```

---

Regarding **list_display** modern approach to modify it is to redefine **get_list_display**:

Original definition just returns `self.list_display`:

```
class ModelAdmin:
    def get_list_display(self, request):
        """
        Return a sequence containing the fields to be displayed on the
        changelist.
        """
        return self.list_display
```

So you can provide:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_list_display(self, request):
        user = request.user
        if user.is_superuser:
            list_display = ['field1', 'field2']
        else:
            list_display = ['field1']
        return list_display
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a less hackish way is described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16115125/710394

```
def get_list_display(self, request):
    ...whatever logic you need here...
```