# create Django ModelAdmin classes dynamically

Tags: python, django, dynamic

I have a whole bunch of models of 3 different types (I have 3 abstract base models, let's say Bread, Eggs, and Beer) and lots of models that inherit one of those three).

I would like to register the concrete models with the admin differently based on their abstract base class, without having to write a separate ModelAdmin class for each one (ie I want to write only 3 ModelAdmin classes - one for each abstract base class). Each type of concrete model has a set of fields that I want displayed (they are different on different concrete models, but in a well-defined way, and I can get a list of the fields I want displayed on an Egg model easily).  Example:

```
#abstract base class for Egg
class Egg(models.Model):
    fields = ...

    def get_only_concrete_fields(self):
        'Return all fields defined on a child of Egg that are not defined on Egg'
        return concrete_fields

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

#concrete class
class WhiteEgg(Egg):
    morefields = ...

#concrete class
class BrownEgg(Egg):
    otherfields = ...
```

So what I want to do is register both WhiteEgg and BrownEgg in the admin (without having to write a separate modeladmin class for each), and I want to set list_display to the result of get_only_concrete_fields(), plus a few (not all) hand-selected fields from Egg.  I know their is a get_list_display() (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/16115125/710394) but I don't think it gets the model, so I can't call get_only_concrete_fields().

I have also tried looping over the models like below, defining list_display for each, and registering each model with a "base" ModelAdmin, but that doesn't work because it just reassigns that modeladmin in each iteration of the loop.

```
for models in all_egg_models:
    modeladmin = MyModelAdmin #or deepcopy(MyModelAdmin)  -also doesn't work
    fieldnames = ...the fields i want...
    setattr(modeladmin, 'list_display', fieldnames)
    admin.site.register(model, modeladmin)
```

I'm stuck - how can I do this, and DRY?

Comment: doh.  yep, that does it.  thanks! can you switch your comment to an answer so i can accept it and give you credit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea of overriding the `get_list_display` method sounds good.

In the method, you can access the model with `self.model`.