# How to make django screen dynamic with user choices?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

So i work in a company and we constantly need to add view fields for the user, I would like to know if there is a way to make this option available to the end user, for example a dropdown with the options that the model admin where he is allowing.

Today we use the django way of doing admin, for example:

```py
    list_display = (
        'course',
        'class',
        'discipline',
        'teacher',
        'start_date',
        'end_date'
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this what you are looking for, but give a try: [How can I dynamically specify the "list_display" attribute of a django ModelAdmin class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16115124/how-can-i-dynamically-specify-the-list-display-attribute-of-a-django-modeladmi)

A kind regard

Emilio